# Passing drawable list in to decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),drawable, 50, 50);

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I am making a layout with multiple ImageButtons but when I run it it crashes down because of java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: I tried to make heap size = large, it worked but the app became slow because it is taking a large memory size now I want to re-size all these images using the below method and i do not know how to give it all the resources I have

```
decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable(), 50, 50);
```

but i do not know how to make the second parameter change in

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable(), 50, 50);
}
```

So I can resize all images

this is my code Resources are(family, romance, budget , luxury, amusement , entertainment , snow_activity , culture ) :

public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
int year ;
int month ;
int day ;
```

int[] drawable = new int[]{R.drawable.family, R.drawable.romance ,R.drawable.beach,
        R.drawable.budget, R.drawable.snow_activity, R.drawable.amusement,
        R.drawable.luxury, R.drawable.entertainment,R.drawable.culture};

ImageView imageView;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    year = extras.getInt("year");
    day = extras.getInt("day");
    month = extras.getInt("month");



    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.family, options);
    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
    String imageType = options.outMimeType;

    BitmapFactory.Options options1 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.romance, options);
    int imageHeight1 = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth1 = options.outWidth;
    String imageType1 = options.outMimeType;

    BitmapFactory.Options options2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.culture, options);
    int imageHeight2 = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth2 = options.outWidth;
    String imageType2 = options.outMimeType;

    BitmapFactory.Options options3 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.beach, options);
    int imageHeight3 = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth3 = options.outWidth;
    String imageType3 = options.outMimeType;

    BitmapFactory.Options options4 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.beach, options);
    int imageHeight4 = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth4 = options.outWidth;
    String imageType4 = options.outMimeType;

    BitmapFactory.Options options5 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.beach, options);
    int imageHeight5 = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth5 = options.outWidth;
    String imageType5  = options.outMimeType;

    BitmapFactory.Options options6 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.beach, options);
    int imageHeight6 = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth6 = options.outWidth;
    String imageType6 = options.outMimeType;

    BitmapFactory.Options options7 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.beach, options);
    int imageHeight7 = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth7 = options.outWidth;
    String imageType7 = options.outMimeType;

    BitmapFactory.Options options8 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.beach, options);
    int imageHeight8 = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth8 = options.outWidth;
    String imageType8 = options.outMimeType;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {



        imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), drawable[i], 50, 50));


    }

    calculateInSampleSize( options , imageWidth , imageHeight);
    calculateInSampleSize( options1 , imageWidth1 , imageHeight1);
    calculateInSampleSize( options2 , imageWidth2 , imageHeight2);
    calculateInSampleSize( options3 , imageWidth3 , imageHeight3);
    calculateInSampleSize( options4 , imageWidth4 , imageHeight4);
    calculateInSampleSize( options5 , imageWidth5 , imageHeight5);
    calculateInSampleSize( options6 , imageWidth6 , imageHeight6);
    calculateInSampleSize(options7, imageWidth7, imageHeight7);
    calculateInSampleSize(options8, imageWidth8, imageHeight8);







}




public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 4;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}



public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

}

Comment: It is unclear what you want to actually achieve and what "the second parameter" means. Perhaps you can add more information and list what you have already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way:

public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
int year ;
int month ;
int day ;












@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    year = extras.getInt("year");
    day = extras.getInt("day");
    month = extras.getInt("month");
    ImageButton imageButton= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.family)  ; ;
    ImageButton imageButton1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.romance);
    ImageButton imageButton2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.culture);
    ImageButton imageButton3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.snow);
    ImageButton imageButton4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.beach);
    ImageButton imageButton5 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.budget);
    ImageButton imageButton6 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.entertament);
    ImageButton imageButton7 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.amusement);
    ImageButton imageButton8 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.luxury);

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.family, options);
    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
    String imageType = options.outMimeType;

    BitmapFactory.Options options1 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.romance, options);
    int imageHeight1 = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth1 = options.outWidth;
    String imageType1 = options.outMimeType;

    BitmapFactory.Options options2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.culture, options);
    int imageHeight2 = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth2 = options.outWidth;
    String imageType2 = options.outMimeType;

    BitmapFactory.Options options3 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.beach, options);
    int imageHeight3 = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth3 = options.outWidth;
    String imageType3 = options.outMimeType;

    BitmapFactory.Options options4 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.beach, options);
    int imageHeight4 = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth4 = options.outWidth;
    String imageType4 = options.outMimeType;

    BitmapFactory.Options options5 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.beach, options);
    int imageHeight5 = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth5 = options.outWidth;
    String imageType5  = options.outMimeType;

    BitmapFactory.Options options6 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.beach, options);
    int imageHeight6 = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth6 = options.outWidth;
    String imageType6 = options.outMimeType;

    BitmapFactory.Options options7 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.beach, options);
    int imageHeight7 = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth7 = options.outWidth;
    String imageType7 = options.outMimeType;

    BitmapFactory.Options options8 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.beach, options);
    int imageHeight8 = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth8 = options.outWidth;
    String imageType8 = options.outMimeType;





    imageButton.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.family, 100, 100));
    imageButton1.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.romance, 100, 100));
    imageButton2.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.culture,100, 100));
    imageButton3.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.budget, 100, 100));
    imageButton4.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.budget, 100, 100));
    imageButton5.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.entertainment, 100, 100));
    imageButton6.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.snow_activity, 100, 100));
    imageButton7.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.amusement, 100, 100));
    imageButton8.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.luxury, 100, 100));





    calculateInSampleSize( options , imageWidth , imageHeight);
    calculateInSampleSize( options1 , imageWidth1 , imageHeight1);
    calculateInSampleSize( options2 , imageWidth2 , imageHeight2);
    calculateInSampleSize( options3 , imageWidth3 , imageHeight3);
    calculateInSampleSize( options4 , imageWidth4 , imageHeight4);
    calculateInSampleSize( options5 , imageWidth5 , imageHeight5);
    calculateInSampleSize( options6 , imageWidth6 , imageHeight6);
    calculateInSampleSize(options7, imageWidth7, imageHeight7);
    calculateInSampleSize(options8, imageWidth8, imageHeight8);







}




public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 4;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}




public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

}